# Using Automapper.TypeMap to map a Property by name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am using `AutoMapper` to map my MVC `ViewModels` to a `DTO` and back again, and was wondering if it was possible to utilize a `TypeMap` from `AutoMapper` to map a value via only a property name?

My scenario is this:

1. I map a `ViewModel` to a `DTO` via Automapper.
2. I send the `DTO` over a WCF call, which fails validation.
3. I get a `FaultException` back with the name of the `DTO` field that failed.
4. I need to set `ModelState` dictionary with the name of the `ViewModel` property that failed, and the error message. This allows me to highlight the errored field on the screen.

So my issue lies in being able to map the `string` name of the `DTO` property that failed, back to the `ViewModel` property. I would like to do something like this:

```
var typemap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(DTO), typeof(Model))
string erroredPropertyName = "Prop1"; // Really extracted from my Fault

// This is the bit that doesn't exist, and I need help with......
//  string destination = typemap.GetDestinationFor(erroredPropertyName);

ModelState.Add(destination, errorMessage);
```

Is this at all possible? I don't mind using `Reflection` if I have to, but would prefer not to use it if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a nice way of doing this via `AutoMapper` in the end:

```
    public PropertyInfo MapDestinationPropertyNameToSourceProperty<TSource, TDestination>(string propertyName)
    {
        var typeMap =  GetTypeMap<TSource, TDestination>();

        var sourcePropName = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps().Where(m => m.DestinationProperty.Name == propertyName).Select(x => x.SourceMember.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePropName))
            return null;

        return typeMap.SourceType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == sourcePropName);            
    }
```

This allows me to pass in the name of the Destination property, and return the `PropertyInfo` of the property that it was mapped from.

I could have just returned the Source Property Name, however I wanted the full `PropertyInfo` object so that I could look up some Custom Attributes on the property that hold my error messages.

Comment: Where is `GetTypeMap` defined? Is this for a really old version of AutoMapper that no longer surfaces this API?